# NodeJS old lockfile issue

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, frontend

I have an Angular site which is built on Node version 8. I have recently upgraded Node on the server and now when I run `npm install` I get the following errors.

I tried different things already,

- I have deleted the package-lock.json file and run that again
- I ran "npm install -g npm@"latest-V"".
- I tried to delete node-sass and install it again

But every "npm" command ends up with following errors

```
npm ERR! code 1

npm ERR! path /var/www/web-folder/abc.com/node_modules/node-sass

npm ERR! command failed

npm ERR! command sh -c node scripts/build.js

npm ERR! Building: /usr/bin/node /var/www/web-folder/abc.com/htdocs/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=

npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok

npm ERR! gyp verb cli [

npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/usr/bin/node',

npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/var/www/web-folder/abc.com/htdocs/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',

npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',

npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',

npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',

npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',

npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',

npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='

npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]

npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0

npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.14.0 | linux | x64

npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []

npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []

npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory

npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []

npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "/usr/bin/python3" in the PATH

npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: /usr/bin/python3

npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/var/www/web-folder/abc.com/htdocs/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)

npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/var/www/web-folder/abc.com/htdocs/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)

npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/var/www/web-folder/abc.com/htdocs/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)

npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /var/www/web-folder/abc.com/htdocs/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16

npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /var/www/web-folder/abc.com/htdocs/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5

npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /var/www/web-folder/abc.com/htdocs/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5

npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)

npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  /usr/bin/python3 Error: not found: /usr/bin/python3

npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/var/www/web-folder/abc.com/htdocs/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)

npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/var/www/web-folder/abc.com/htdocs/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)

npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/var/www/web-folder/abc.com/htdocs/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)

npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /var/www/web-folder/abc.com/htdocs/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16

npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /var/www/web-folder/abc.com/htdocs/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5

npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /var/www/web-folder/abc.com/htdocs/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5

npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) {

npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'

npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }

npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "/usr/bin/python3", you can set the PYTHON env variable.

npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (/var/www/web-folder/abc.com/htdocs/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:484:19)

npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (/var/www/web-folder/abc.com/htdocs/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:406:16)

npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at F (/var/www/web-folder/abc.com/htdocs/node_modules/which/which.js:68:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at E (/var/www/web-folder/abc.com/htdocs/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /var/www/web-folder/abc.com/htdocs/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /var/www/web-folder/abc.com/htdocs/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /var/www/web-folder/abc.com/htdocs/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 3.10.0-862.14.4.el7.x86_64
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/var/www/web-folder/abc.com/htdocs/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /var/www/web-folder/abc.com/htdocs/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.14.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1
```

Comment: If you read it closely it says you need Python 3 installed which is a requirement of node-gyp for native modules like node-sass. Note this is only required to build/install modules, not run them

Comment: Thank you Joe,
I have installed Python3 all other errors are gone, But, I am still getting the following errors.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /var/www/web-folder/abc.com/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: /usr/bin/node /var/www/web-folder/abc.com/htdocs/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/usr/bin/node',